# How can I get input edges of a given vertex on a directed graph?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-graph

I have a directed graph and I want to fetch the parent of a given vertex.

Say I have the graph `1 -> 2 -> 3`, I hold the vertex `2` and I want to get vertex `1`.

My vertex and graph definitions:

```
struct TreeVertex   {  int id = -1;  };

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::directedS,
    TreeVertex
    > tree_t;
```

An MVCE showing what I want to achieve (see [online here](http://ideone.com/yz64cC)):

```
int main() {
    tree_t tree;
    auto v1 = boost::add_vertex( tree );    
    auto v2 = boost::add_vertex( tree );    
    auto v3 = boost::add_vertex( tree );    
    boost::add_edge( v1, v2, tree );
    boost::add_edge( v2, v3, tree );

// attempt to get the input edge of v2
    auto pair_it_edge = boost::in_edges( v2, tree ); // FAILS TO BUILD  
    auto v = boost::source( *pair_it_edge.first ); // should be v1
}
```

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798465/) suggests transforming the graph into a `BidirectionalGraph` but I need to keep it directed.

Question: Is this possible ? How can I get the incoming edge of `v2`, so that I can extract `v1` ?

Comment: Without using a bidirectional graph, you will have to do a brute force search of all the nodes, looking for one that has vertex 2 as its child.  It may be worthwhile to create a temporary biderectional copy of your graph to save doing the search.

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm not sure I have gotten bidirectionnal graphs correctly: if they are bidirectionnal, how can I have the `1<->2` edge, and not the `2<->3`, using `boost::in_edges()` ? Something unclear to me on [the page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/BidirectionalGraph.html).

Comment: @ravenspoint if you are going to have a temporary graph anyway, why not rather create a second directed graph where all the edges are inverted... Using the bidirectional one you'll have to go and lookup in the original graph if the edge you are considering is an in or out edge... I might be missing something, but I think it would be cleaner and even have a bit less of overhead. In pseudo: `for (out_edges(v, tree_copy)){ print target as source and vicecersa }`  vs. `for(edges(v, tree_bi_copy)){check if in or out. if in print else skip}`

Comment: @dingalapadum You are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using a bidirectional graph, you will have to do a brute force search of all the nodes, looking for one that has vertex 2 as its child.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
using namespace std;
   using namespace boost;

struct TreeVertex   {  int id = -1;  };

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::directedS,
    TreeVertex
    > tree_t;

    tree_t tree;


int main() {


    auto v1 = boost::add_vertex( tree );    
    auto v2 = boost::add_vertex( tree );    
    auto v3 = boost::add_vertex( tree );    
    boost::add_edge( v1, v2, tree );
    boost::add_edge( v2, v3, tree );

    int looking_for = 2;

    typename graph_traits < tree_t >::out_edge_iterator ei, ei_end;
    for( int v = 0; v < num_edges( tree ); v++ )
    for (boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = out_edges(v, tree); ei != ei_end; ++ei) {
    auto source = boost::source ( *ei, tree );
    auto target = boost::target ( *ei, tree );
    if( target == looking_for )
        std::cout << "There is an edge from " << source <<  " to " << target << std::endl;

// create an inverted edge tree to search for parents
tree_t invtree;
boost::add_edge( v2, v1, invtree );
boost::add_edge( v1, v3, invtree );
typename graph_traits < tree_t >::adjacency_iterator it, it_end;
for (tie(it, it_end) = adjacent_vertices(v2, invtree ); it != it_end; ++it) 
{
    std::cout << "There is an inv edge from " <<  v2
        << " to " << *it << std::endl;
}


    return 0;
}
```

It may be worthwhile to create a temporary tree with inverted edges as a 'copy' of your graph to simplify the search for parents.  Something like invtree at the end of the code posted.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, I believe you are true and there is no other way. The best solution among the two would depend on the graphs size and structure, probably. Anyhow, I think I solved my problem as I think I _can_ finaly use a Bidirectionnal graph.